# PySide2 QWizard non linear pages

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qwizard

I am trying to change my code from PyQt5 to PySide2. Most of the my scripts I simply have to change imports from PyQt5 to PySide2 and it works the same. However I tried to rework the licensewizard example in the Qt documentation from PyQt5 to PySide2. In PyQt5 it works perfectly, However, in PySide2 I get a error with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV). The PySide2 qwizard code for linear wizards like the class wizard example, works fine. Does anyone knows why it fails with the non linear wizards and why I get that error?

Thanks

The code below works for PyQt5. Replacing PyQt5 with PySide2 I get an error

Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

```
class IntroductionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IntroductionPage, self).__init__()

        self.setTitle("Introduction")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("set this up")
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class1

class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__()
        self.setTitle("Choices")
        self.setSubTitle("Choose 1")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.class_selected1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        if self.radButton2.isChecked():

            return Wizard.class2
        elif self.radButton3.isChecked():

            return Wizard.class2
        else:
            return Wizard.conclusion

class ClassesPage2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassesPage2, self).__init__()
        #self.page = QWizardPage()
        self.setTitle("Classes for grade 2")
        self.setSubTitle("Please select a Class")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.class_selected2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.conclusion

class ClassesPage3(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassesPage3, self).__init__()
        self.setTitle("Classes for grade 3")
        self.setSubTitle("Please select a Class")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.class_selected3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.conclusion

class ConclusionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConclusionPage, self).__init__()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Wizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    num_of_pages = 5
    (intro, class1, class2, class3, conclusion) = range(num_of_pages)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__()
        self.setPage(self.intro, IntroductionPage())

        self.setPage(self.class1, ClassesPage1())
        self.setPage(self.class2, ClassesPage2())
        self.setPage(self.class3, ClassesPage3())
        self.setPage(self.conclusion, ConclusionPage())
        self.setStartId(self.intro)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    wizard = Wizard()

    wizard.setWindowTitle("Set Up")
    wizard.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.MacStyle)
    wizard.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am trying to add my code but struggling with formatting problems. working on it

Comment: add it, I will modify it with a suitable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that unlike PyQt5, PySide2 requires that you pass a parent, in your case the solution is to change the constructors of the classes:

```
class Some_Page(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Some_Page, self).__init__()
```

to:

```
class Some_Page(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Some_Page, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When we add a page, we pass the parent to him:

```
class Wizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    num_of_pages = 5
    (intro, class1, class2, class3, conclusion) = range(num_of_pages)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPage(self.intro, IntroductionPage(self))
        self.setPage(self.class1, ClassesPage1(self))
        self.setPage(self.class2, ClassesPage2(self))
        self.setPage(self.class3, ClassesPage3(self))
        self.setPage(self.conclusion, ConclusionPage(self))
        self.setStartId(self.intro)
```

Complete Code:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys

class IntroductionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(IntroductionPage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setTitle("Introduction")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Welcome to the One Inc™'s Teacher Interactive Accessment tool. Follow the prompts to set up your Mark Sheet")
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.class1

class ClassesPage1(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTitle("Choices")
        self.setSubTitle("Choose 1")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('1C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        if self.radButton2.isChecked():

            return Wizard.class2
        elif self.radButton3.isChecked():

            return Wizard.class2
        else:
            return Wizard.conclusion

class ClassesPage2(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #self.page = QWizardPage()
        self.setTitle("Classes for grade 2")
        self.setSubTitle("Please select a Class")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2A')
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2B')
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('2C')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.class_selected2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.conclusion

class ClassesPage3(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassesPage3, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setTitle("Classes for grade 3")
        self.setSubTitle("Please select a Class")

        self.radButton1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3A', self)
        self.radButton2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3B', self)
        self.radButton3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('3C', self)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.radButton3)
        self.class_selected3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def nextId(self):
        return Wizard.conclusion

class ConclusionPage(QtWidgets.QWizardPage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ConclusionPage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class Wizard(QtWidgets.QWizard):
    num_of_pages = 5
    (intro, class1, class2, class3, conclusion) = range(num_of_pages)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Wizard, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setPage(self.intro, IntroductionPage(self))
        self.setPage(self.class1, ClassesPage1(self))
        self.setPage(self.class2, ClassesPage2(self))
        self.setPage(self.class3, ClassesPage3(self))
        self.setPage(self.conclusion, ConclusionPage(self))
        self.setStartId(self.intro)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    wizard = Wizard()

    wizard.setWindowTitle("Set Up")
    wizard.setWizardStyle(QtWidgets.QWizard.MacStyle)
    wizard.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: eyllanesc. How do you diagnose errors like this. I am bumping into a simillar error with QtCharts when I try to change from PyQt5 to PySide2. Even if i pass the *args, **kwargs

Comment: @GodwinMafireyi Generally I try to find the line that generates the error, I comment the lines until the application works, and then I analyze the last one that I comment because it is probably the cause of the error.

Comment: If you have problems post a question pointing out the inconveniences.